# Remove fake experience from resume

Tags: job-search, work-experience

I completed my Btech in 2009. I tried for a government job for 3 years but did not succeed. Then I put a fake experience of 3 years on my resume and got a job in a software multinational.

Now my genuine experience is around 5 years.

I want to start a new job search to move to another company.

How can I remove the fake experience from my resume, and to avoid mentioning the experience gap in my resume?

Comment: I think that the delete key will be sufficient for removing lies from your resume. As far as the gap goes, don't fill it with anymore falshoods. Most employers won't care too much about a five year old gap.

Comment: You can also keep it in if you want, albeit in the form of a startup you did. it's so old nobody is going to check it now

Comment: No. Don't keep it in if you want. Lying on your resume is never ever a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Delete it and just leave out the gap unless asked. You have 5 years experience now, people aren't that interested in much further back. If asked just tell the truth, 'I was unemployed, self-employed, freelancing...etc,. '

Comment: But my current company mentioned In offer letter as "we are considering your 3 years of experience as relevant".

Comment: Shall I tell that I worked in a start up and it's closed now and not able to contact any one. That's the reason I removed that experience.

Comment: Only if it is true

Comment: Sooner or later you will get caught if you lie. Lying about your employment will get you fired on the spot in most countries. Good luck explaining that in the next interview in a positive way...